# Why does Ruby incorrectly parse strings with commas as floats?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

The crux of my question is as follows:

```
irb(main):001:0> "5,280".to_f
=> 5.0
```

**Why does Ruby do this?**

I could *almost* understand `"5,280".to_i == 5` since `,` is a decimal-type delimiter in some locales, but the loss of precision here is baffling to me, especially since `"5.280".to_f` returns `5.28` as expected.

Is this just a bug?

Ruby version in case it matters:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
```

Comment: What do you expect `"5,280".to_f` to return?

Comment: `to_i` and `to_f` are extremely lazy and permissive when it comes to conversion. If you want robust conversion with error checking, use `Float()`

Comment: What should `"5djfsdkjfhs".to_f` return? It could either raise an error, or make a best guess (which is what it does) and return `5.0`. That's exactly what happens here, too. Ruby does not try to guess locales when converting between strings and numbers; the string can *only* contain digits, or `.` for a decimal point.

Comment: 'What should "5djfsdkjfhs".to_f return?'
An error

Comment: @spickermann An error or 5.28

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Maybe. Or perhaps, as the ruby language designers chose,  `to_f` should be a safe operation which always returns a float and never errors.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist If `"5,280".to_f  == 5.28`, then logically we equally argue that `"5,280".to_i == 5280`. And in that case, we'd end up in a bizarre scenario where `"5,280".to_f.to_i != "5,280".to_i`.

Comment: ...which is why I'd prefer an error. If `to_f` is meant to be "safe" and not return an error it should return `nil` or something instead of nonsense, but that's me. I'm not here to argue about language design. I got my answer.

Comment: @close-voter Please look at the question and the accepted answer again and tell me where is the opinion. Why does Ruby do this? Because it only looks at the left of a string. Because it calls a C function. No opinion here: just facts.

Comment: `to_f` returning `nil` would not be nonsense? (Even though `nil.to_f == 0`?) OK. To each their own.

Comment: 25¢, a smile came to my face when I read "incorrectly" in your title. Yes, Ruby has bugs, but ain't one. A quick google search makes it clear that disallowing the use of a comma as a decimal point was a design decision. Are there computer languages that allow the use of a comma as the decimal separate without setting a built-in constant or global variable? (I don't know.)

Comment: If one wants an uncompromising conversion of a string to a float, [Kernel::Float](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) is the method of choice. Ruby's general permissiveness in converting objects to other objects is often just for convenience. For example, there's no need for a way to convert `nil` to a float, but sometimes it's convenient to make use of 
 `nil.to_f #=> 0.0`, as in `arr.sum { |e| e.to_f }` where some array elements may be `nil`. Granted, that's not everyone's cup of tea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby simply call `strtod` C function   https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/38caab29bc759be2694013fc3930116e64fcc1d4/object.c#L3278

```
d = strtod(p, &end);
```

and strtod function has something like this:

```
/*
 * Count the number of digits in the mantissa (including the decimal
 * point), and also locate the decimal point.
 */

decPt = -1;
for (mantSize = 0; ; mantSize += 1)
{
c = *p;
if (!isdigit(c)) {
    if ((c != '.') || (decPt >= 0)) {
    break;
    }
    decPt = mantSize;
}
p += 1;
}
```

https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-10/tcl/compat/strtod.c

according to `if ((c != '.') || (decPt >= 0)) {
    break;`
 `strtod` stop if find any not dot symbol, for example:

```
irb(main):002:0> "2;58".to_f
=> 2.0
irb(main):003:0> "2@58".to_f
=> 2.0
irb(main):004:0>
```

UPD: this approach is valid for mri 2.6 ruby implementation. In other versions/implementations it's may be different.

Comment: This only applies to the specific version of MRI that you're looking at though. There's no guarantee that every version of Ruby will use `strtod` from libc, not all versions of Ruby will even be written in C. The docs say that `String#to_f` behaves a certain way, the specific implementation in MRI is incidental.

Comment: Thanks, I add note about this in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

From the [fine 2.3.7 manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.7/String.html#method-i-to_f) (but the [current docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_f) say the same thing):

> **to_f → float**
>   Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in `str` as a floating point number. Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at the start of `str`, 0.0 is returned. This method never raises an exception.

So `"5,280".to_f` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. Everything up to (but not including) the comma is a valid number and the extraneous characters (`",280"` in this case) are ignored. The result is the same as calling `'5'.to_f`.

This isn't a bug, it is the expected and documented behavior. This has been the behavior of `String#to_f` since at least [Ruby 1.8.6](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/String.html#method-i-to_f).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is a bug, I think it has to do with what part of the string Ruby considers when it calls to_f.

Ruby looks at the string starting on the left, and any character that is 0-9, the first decimal, and following characters that are 0-9 it will match and try to convert to a float. Anything to the right of that is ignored.

If no characters match that criteria, it returns 0.0.

https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_f

Examples:

```
>>'5.5'.to_f 
=> 5.5

>>'5.5stuff'.to_f 
=> 5.5   

>>'5.stuff5'.to_f 
=> 5.0

>>'5,5'.to_f 
=> 5.0

>>'stuff5.5'.to_f 
=> 0.0
```